# Rules on Parenthesis for Block Variables

Tags: arrays, ruby, block

I ran across the following piece of code while reading *The Ruby Way*:

```
class Array
  def invert
    each_with_object({}).with_index { |(elem, hash), index| hash[elem] = index }
  end
end
```

I want to make sure that I understand what the parenthesis are doing in `(elem, hash)`.

The first method (`each_with_object({})`) will yield two objects to the block. The first object will be the element in the array; the second object will be the hash. The parentheses make sure that those two objects are assigned to different block variables. If I had instead used `{ |elem, index} #code }`, then elem would be an array consisting of the element and the hash. I think that is clear.

My confusion lies with the fact that if I didn't chain these two methods, I would not have to use the parentheses, and instead could use: `each_with_object({}) { |elem, obj #code }`.

What are the rules about when parentheses are necessary in block variables? Why do they differ between the two examples here? My *simplistic* explanation is that, when the methods are not chained, then the yield code looks like `yield (elem, obj)`, but when the methods are chained, the code looks like `yield([elem, obj], index)`. (We can surmise that a second array would be passed in if we chained a third method). Is this correct? Is the object(s) passed in from the last chained method not an array?

I guess instead of all this conjecture, the question boils down to: "What does the yield statement look like when chaining methods that accept blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is only tangentially concerned with blocks and block variables. Rather, it concerns the rules for "disambiguating" arrays.

Let's consider your example:

```
[1,2,3].each_with_object({}).with_index {|(elem, hash), index| hash[elem] = index}
```

We have:

```
enum0 = [1,2,3].each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can see this enumerator's elements by converting it to an array:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [[1, {}], [2, {}], [3, {}]]
```

We next have:

```
enum1 = enum0.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each_with_object({})>:with_index> 
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[[1, {}], 0], [[2, {}], 1], [[3, {}], 2]]
```

You might want to think of `enum1` as a "compound enumerator", but it's just an enumerator.

You see that `enum1` has three elements. These elements are passed to the block by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each). The first is:

```
enum1.first
  #=> [[1, {}], 0]
```

If we had a single block variable, say `a`, then

```
a #=> [[1, {}], 0]
```

We could instead break this down in different ways using "disambiguation". For example, we could write:

```
a,b = [[1, {}], 0]
a #=> [1, {}] 
b #=> 0
```

Now let's stab out all the elements:

```
a,b,c = [[1, {}], 0]
a #=> [1, {}] 
b #=> 0 
c #=> nil
```

Whoops! That's not what we wanted. We've just experienced the "ambiguous" in "disambiguate". We need to write this so that our intentions are unambiguous. We do that by adding parenthesis. By doing so, you are telling Ruby, "decompose the array in this position to its constituent elements". We have:

```
(a,b),c = [[1, {}], 0]
a #=> 1 
b #=> {} 
c #=> 0
```

Disambiguation can be extremely useful. Suppose, for example, a method returned the array:

```
[[1,[2,3],[[4,5],{a: 6}]],7]
```

and we wish to pull out all the individual values. We could do that as follows:

```
(a,(b,c),((d,e),f)),g = [[1,[2,3],[[4,5],{a: 6}]],7]
a #=> 1 
b #=> 2 
c #=> 3 
d #=> 4 
e #=> 5 
f #=> {:a=>6} 
g #=> 7
```

Again, you just have to remember that the parentheses simply mean "decompose the array in this position to its constituent elements".

Comment: "decompose the array in this position to its constituent elements" - This was the key that made it click Cary Swoveland. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The rule is basic: every enumerator has a “signature.” E.g. it yields two parameters, then the proc to be passed should expect two parameters to receive:

```
[1,2,3].each_with_index { |o, i| ...}
```

When the object might be expanded, like hash item, it may be expanded using parenthesis. Assuming, the iterator yields an array, `[*arr]`-like operation is permitted with.

The following example might shed a light on this:

```
[1,2,3].each_with_object('first') # yielding |e,        obj|
       .with_index                # yielding |elem,     idx|
    #  but wait! elem might be expanded here  ⇑⇑⇑⇑
    #                                        |(e, obj), idx|
       .each_with_object('second') do |((elem, fst_obj), snd_idx), trd_obj| 
    puts "e: #{elem}, 1o: #{fst_obj}, 2i: #{snd_idx}, 3o: #{trd_obj}"
end

#⇒ e: 1, 1o: first, 2i: 0, 3o: second
#⇒ e: 2, 1o: first, 2i: 1, 3o: second
#⇒ e: 3, 1o: first, 2i: 2, 3o: second
```